# Implicit conversion from primitive type to Object

Tags: java

Here is this code:

```
int[] someArray = {0, 1, 2, 3};
//System.out.println(someArray[0].toString()); int cannot be dereferenced
// creating Object element with use of primitive element fails
//Object newObject = new Object(someArray[0]); constructor Object in class java.lang.Object cannot be applied to given types;
for(Object someObject : someArray)
{
    // here int is casted to Object
    System.out.println(someObject.toString()); // prints 0, 1, 2, 3
}
```

How does it happen that primitive type variable (element of array) cannot be explicitly casted to Object, however somehow in for loop this primitive element is casted to Object?

Comment: Interesting question. My guess is that the enhanced foreach loop for arrays works by creating some sort of internal iterator class that boxes the given primitive type. I.e. you're not iterating directly over the array, but over a hidden `Iterator<Integer>`.

Comment: You are not casting anywhere in your comments. `int x = 5; System.out.println(((Object) x));` will certainly work correctly, even without a loop.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut The point is, the foreach loop doesn't usually do this sort of cast for you either.

Comment: It just autoboxes to `Integer`, once boxed it is an `Object type` and no primitive anymore. Thus you can substitude within your inheritence tree as with normal classes. So `Object` is a valid substitute for the `Integer` class, also `Number` would be a valid one. `Double` for example wouldn't be a correct substitution and will result in compile time errors.

Comment: My guess above is patently wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since 1.5, the Java compiler will automatically *box* and *unbox* primitive types when the context calls for it. (That is, an `int` gets wrapped in an `Integer` object and vice versa.) This happens when **assigning** between a primitive and an object variable. (Or casting a primitive to an object type.) So, for example, the following code is valid:

```
int i = 123;
Object o = i;
```

The same goes for the implicit assignment `Object someInt = someArray[…]` that the compiler emits for the foreach loop.

The reason why `someArray[0].toString()` doesn't work is that you're not assigning `someArray[0]` to an object typed variable or doing anything else that would tell the compiler to autobox – trying to call a method on a primitive simply isn't recognized as one of the conditions when this should occur.